# How to parse a custom string and create a dictionary from that string?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two type of strings that look something like below

```
string1 = 'ID=mRNA42;Parent=gene19;integrity=0.95;foo=bar'
string2 = 'transcript_id "g3.t1"; gene_id "g3";'
```

I am trying to create a function that will take the above strings as input and return a dictionary according to the string.

for the string1 dictionary, the structure is like

```
attributes = {
    'ID': 'mrna42',
    'Parent': 'gene19',
    'integrity': '0.95',
    'foo': 'bar',
}
```

and for the string2

```
attributes = {
    'transcript_id': 'g3.t1',
    'gene_id': 'g3', 
}
```

My try:

```
def parse_single_feature_line(attributestring):

    attributes = dict()
    for keyvaluepair in attributestring.split(';'):
        for key, value in keyvaluepair.split('='):
            attributes[key] = value
    return attributes
```

I need help to build the function.

Comment: check my answer for simplified answer ... i used your existing function with regex

Answer (score 2):

You can have a global solution with regular expressions:

```
import re

string1 = 'ID=mRNA42;Parent=gene19;integrity=0.95;foo=bar'
string2 = 'transcript_id "g3.t1"; gene_id "g3";'

# Define the regular expression
reg_exp = "([\.\-\w_]+)=([\.\-\w_]+);?|([\.\-\w_]+) \"([\.\-\w_]+)\""

# Get results and filter empty elements in tuples
match = [filter(None, x) for x in re.findall(reg_exp, string1+"\n"+string2)]

# Convert to dict
result = {key:value for key, value in match}
```

This regular expression contains two main groups:

Group A `([\.\-\w_]+)=([\.\-\w_);?` and group B `([\.\-\w_]+) \"([\.\-\w_]+)\"`

Each groups contains another 2 groups, that will match with the name and value pair. Please notice that you may need to adjust these groups to your expected name and values or use `(.*?)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string1 = 'ID=mRNA42;Parent=gene19;integrity=0.95;foo=bar'
string2 = 'transcript_id "g3.t1"; gene_id "g3";'

def str2dict(s):
     result={}
     for i in s.split(";"):
             ele=i.strip()
             if not ele:continue
             if "=" in i:
                     key,val=ele.split("=")
             else:   
                     key,val=ele.split()
             result[key]=val.strip('"')
     return result

str2dict(string1)
str2dict(string2)
```

Comment: I am getting "**ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)**"  while running the script. So can you please check it.

Comment: This comes from the trailing ";" at the end of string2 which yields an additionnal empty string

Answer (score 1):

You can use dict comprehension!

```
>>> string1
'ID=mRNA42;Parent=gene19;integrity=0.95;foo=bar'
>>> string2
'transcript_id "g3.t1"; gene_id "g3";'
>>> {each.split('=')[0]:each.split('=')[1] for each in string1.split(';') if each}
{'foo': 'bar', 'integrity': '0.95', 'ID': 'mRNA42', 'Parent': 'gene19'}
>>> {each.split(' ')[0]:each.split(' ')[1] for each in string2.split(';') if each}
{'': 'gene_id', 'transcript_id': '"g3.t1"'}
```

And to solve the problem you are facing,

```
def parse_single_feature_line(attributestring):
    attributes = dict()
    for keyvaluepair in attributestring.split(';'):
        key,value=keyvaluepair.split('=') # you get a list  when you split keyvaluepair string and not a list of list(if list of lists eg.[["this","these"],["that","those"]] then you can use - for key,value in list_of_lists:)
        attributes[key] = value
    return attributes

print parse_single_feature_line(string1)
```

Comment: you can even simply this... dict(each.split('=') for i in string1.split(';'))  for more details check my answer below. i simplified it

Answer (score 0):

They are different so need to be handled different.

```
def return_dict(string):
    if "=" in string:
        return dict(i.strip().split("=") for i in string.split(";"))
    else:
        return dict([i.strip().split(" ") for i in string.split(";") if len(i.strip().split(" ")) > 1])

return_dict(string1)
return_dict(string2)
```

gives:

```
{'ID': 'mRNA42', 'Parent': 'gene19', 'foo': 'bar', 'integrity': '0.95'}
{'gene_id': '"g3"', 'transcript_id': '"g3.t1"'}
```

Comment: if it is different non char? we can handle this using regex.. re.split('[ =]',string)... check my answer hope you will understand

Answer (score 0):

First solution: split on the space and strip the quotes on the second half of the result:

```
>>> key, val = 'transcript_id "g3.t1"'.split(" ", maxsplit=1)
>>> val = val.strip('"')
>>> key
'transcript_id'
>>> val
'g3.t1'
```

Second solution (more generic): use a regexp to capture the parts:

```
>>> import re
>>> match = re.search(r'([a-z_]+) "(.+?)"', 'transcript_id "g3.t1"')
>>> key, val = match.groups()
>>> key
'transcript_id'
>>> val
'g3.t1'
```

If you know beforehand which of your two formats you have in a given string or file, you can pass a callback to do the substring parsing, ie:

```
def parse_line(attributestring, itemparse):
    attributes = dict()
    for keyvaluepair in attributestring.split(';'):
        if not keyvaluepair:
            # empty string due to a trailing ";"
            continue   
        for key, value in itemparse(keyvaluepair):
            attributes[key] = value
    return attributes


def parse_eq(kvstring):
    return kvstring.split("=")

def parse_space(kvstring):
    key, val = 'transcript_id "g3.t1"'.split(" ", maxsplit=1)
    return key, val.strip('"')

d1 = parse_line(string1, parse_eq)
d2 = parse_line(string2, parse_space)
```

Answer (score 0):

simplified version, you can add delimiter to split in regex for more string split,

```
string1 = 'ID=mRNA42;Parent=gene19;integrity=0.95;foo=bar'
string2 = 'transcript_id "g3.t1"; gene_id "g3";'
import re

def parse_single_feature_line(string):
    attributes = dict(re.split('[ =]', i.strip()) for i in string.split(';') if i)
    return attributes

print parse_single_feature_line(string1)
print parse_single_feature_line(string2)
```